# How to pull the last before value from windows URL in C#?

Tags: c#

I would like to know how can i get the value of last 2 nd part of the url ???

```
Input   : \\\192.168.XX.XX\ABC\XYZZ\1234\58\Hello <br/>
Expected Output : 58
```

Please help me, on the code snippet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the [`Uri` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) (which makes sense when working with URLs), you can make use of its `Segments` property:

```
var uri = new Uri(@"\\192.168.XX.XX\ABC\XYZZ\1234\58\Hello");
var number = uri.Segments[uri.Segments.Length-2].TrimEnd('/');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [string.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx)

```
string str = @"\\\192.168.XX.XX\ABC\XYZZ\1234\58\Hello <br/>";
var arr = str.Split('\\');
string val = arr[arr.Length-2];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use System.IO.Path:

```
var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(@"\\\192.168.XX.XX\ABC\XYZZ\1234\58\Hello");
// dir now contains \\\192.168.XX.XX\ABC\XYZZ\1234\58
var result = Path.GetFileName(dir)
// result = 58
```

Or shorter:

```
Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(@"\\\192.168.XX.XX\ABC\XYZZ\1234\58\Hello"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string.LastIndexOf(@"\")` to get the index and call `Substring`

example:

```
string s = @"\\\192.168.XX.XX\ABC\XYZZ\1234\58\Hello";
string ns = s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1); //Hello
```

**UPDATE**:

Use Split to get 2nd Last backslash:

```
 string[] arr = s.Split('\\');
 ns = arr[arr.Length - 2]; //58
```

Comment: for first output is hello while he need 58 not hello

Answer (score 0):

You can use substring method.

```
        string s=@"\192.168.XX.XX\ABC\XYZZ\1234\58\Hello";
        var abc = s.Substring((s.LastIndexOf("\\")-2), 2);
```